# C# code behind not working after load() jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an update panel in aspx page.
Click on one of the button show a div from code behind, and load to that div element from another page

```
  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, typeof(UpdatePanel), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                        "UpsalePopup();  $('#MyDiv').load('PopUp/UpsaleAdv.aspx  #UpsaleAdvPanel');"
                        , true);
```

And its working perfect.

After user close that div (have only picture)
click on asp Button to do function on server side, go to '/UpsaleAdv.aspx' and show it as 404.

Is the load() function ruin my page ? how can I prevent it or solve it ?

Comment: is the error that it is going to `404` page ??

Comment: yes, but what i'm looking for is not the redirecting to this page (UpsaleAdv.aspx), I expected to get the code behind from the original aspx page (with the panel)

Comment: but in your code, you have passed url as `PopUp/UpsaleAdv.aspx`

Comment: tell me one thing, to which page it should get redirected ??

Comment: None! the original page is 'myaspx.aspx' on it I open div that load :$('#MyDiv').load('PopUp/UpsaleAdv.aspx  #UpsaleAdvPanel');" and i want to get the code behind of myaspx.aspx

Comment: I still didnt get you exactly what your error is and what exactly do you want. Can you explain it in more clearly

Comment: After close the div, clicking on asp Button in the myaspx.aspx page do NOT go the   btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) function in myaspx.aspx code behind. what he is doing: retirect to  '/UpsaleAdv.aspx' and show it as 404.

Answer (score 0):

The page `'PopUp/UpsaleAdv.aspx'` was an aspx page with `<form>` tag.

And after do this function:

`$('#MyDiv').load('PopUp/UpsaleAdv.aspx  #UpsaleAdvPanel');"`

it makes the current page (`myaspa.aspx`) to get the funcunality from `PopUp/UpsaleAdv.aspx`

And once I removed the `<form>` tag and replaced the page to inherit from master page all works perfect.